# I need a help on extracting scores of each team from this array, but I still don't get how to solve it

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void) {
     
        char *matchs[10] = { "2:3", "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", "55:7", "7:2", "17:2", 
                              "2:17", "17:18"};
    
        char *(*pt) = matchs; // Pointing to array matchs
    
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    
            printf("%s ", *++(pt));
    
        }
    
        return 0;        
    }
```

Our football team finished the championship with ten matches. The result of each match look like "x:y". Results of all matches are recorded in the array

For example: `["3:1", "22:2", "0:19", ...]`

Write a function that takes such list and counts the points of each team in the championship. Rules for counting points for each match:

```
    if x>y - 3 points
    if x<y - 0 point
    if x = y - 1 points
```

We cannot use `stoi()` or token function instead using only pointer, `while` loop and `for` loops extract data.

This piece of code it is what I tried but it is not working.

OUTPUT : 0:0 15:12 2:13 1:5 55:7 7:2 17:2 2:17 17:18

Comment: Make it specific which part you cannot understand. Do you understand how pointer works? Do you understand how to parse characters? Do you understand how to tokenize  string separated by `:` ?

Comment: I don't understand how to write a pointer that can point to each character of this array since the  score of each match was recorded as "x:y". In short, I want to know how to write a pointer which can point to each character of array match[10] when placed inside a loop, So that we can extract the scores of X and Y separately by using while(match != '\0'){ DO SOMETHING} follow by  while(match[i] != ':') {DO SOMETHING}

Answer (score 1):

char * matches[10] is an array of char pointers, or an array of strings. We can point to any one string in the array with matches[index] or *(matches + index), which decays to a char pointer(string). We can then find a specific char within this with dereference with [] or with pointer arithmetic.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *matches[10] = { "2:3", "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", "55:7", "7:2", "17:2", 
                              "2:17", "17:18"};

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    /*Dereference once will give a char pointer (string), dereference twice
    will give us a single char*/
    printf("\n%s", *(matches + i)); //This will print the whole string, i.e. "2:3" or {2,:,3,0}
    printf("\nx: %c", *(*(matches + i) + 0)); //This will print '2'
    printf("\ny: %c", *(*(matches + i) + 2)); //This will print '3'
    /*Note we can compare chars directly, as they are essentially 1 byte ints, so
    ('2' < '3') will evaluate to 1 (true)*/
    /*Note we will also run into problems with scores that are multiple chars, such as 17:20
    We can work around this with an if statement checking if a char is ':', which 
    divides the numbers. We can then print them out or write them to a file or
    whatever. Note we can find a literal accurate integer representation of a char
    without stoi or atoi by doing: int number = '9' - '0'; This will give the number 9.
    */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: To elaborate on point about counting scores that are multiple chars,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int str_to_int(const char * string, int length)
{
    int i;
    int num = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int place_value = pow(10, (length - i - 1));
        num += place_value * (*(string + i) - '0');
    }
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    char *matches[10] = { "2:3", "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", "55:7", "7:2", "17:2", 
                              "2:17", "17:18"};

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        /*Dereference once will give a char pointer (string), dereference twice
        will give us a single char*/
        printf("\n%s", *(matches + i)); //This will print the whole string, i.e. "2:3" or {2,:,3,0}
        char current; //To hold the current char we are reading.
        int counter = 0;
        char number[5]; //To hold a string representation of a number
    
        do
        {
            current = *(*(matches + i) + counter);
            if(current != ':')
                *(number + counter) = current;
            
            counter++;
        }
        while (current != ':');
        *(number + counter - 1) = '\0';
        //We now have the x value.
        printf("\nx: %d", str_to_int(number, counter - 1));
        int counter2 = 0;
        do
        {
            current = *(*(matches + i) + counter);
            *(number + counter2) = current;
            
            counter2++;
            counter++;
        }
        while (current != '\0');
        //Now we have y
        printf("\ny: %d", str_to_int(number, counter2 - 1));
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will be able to find scores with multiple characters.

EDIT 2: Output:

```
2:3                                                                                                                                                                                  
x: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 3                                                                                                                                                                                 
0:0                                                                                                                                                                                  
x: 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
15:12                                                                                                                                                                                
x: 15                                                                                                                                                                                
y: 12                                                                                                                                                                                
2:13                                                                                                                                                                                 
x: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 13                                                                                                                                                                                
1:5                                                                                                                                                                                  
x: 1                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 5                                                                                                                                                                                 
55:7                                                                                                                                                                                 
x: 55                                                                                                                                                                                
y: 7                                                                                                                                                                                 
7:2                                                                                                                                                                                  
x: 7                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
17:2                                                                                                                                                                                 
x: 17                                                                                                                                                                                
y: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
2:17                                                                                                                                                                                 
x: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
y: 17                                                                                                                                                                                
17:18                                                                                                                                                                                
x: 17                                                                                                                                                                                
y: 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the entire solution. You can get a pointer of team y's score by finding `:` character in each result. (See how I get `str_y` pointer).
I think the most tricky part is to get the score of each team without using functions like stoi. I did write my solution but I recommend you write this by yourself first (especially if this is homework task).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int point_x = 0;
    int point_y = 0;
    const char *matches[10] = { "2:3", "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", "55:7", "7:2", "17:2", "2:17", "17:18" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // This pointer points the first character of each result
        const char* match = matches[i];

        // Get the pointer of ":" of this result
        const char* separator = match;
        while( *separator != ':' && *separator != '\0' ) separator++;
        // You would need to handle error when ':' is not found but here just assumes all the results contain ":".

        // To make it easy to understand prepare two pointers to point each score in a result.
        const char* str_x = match;
        const char* str_y = separator+1; // next character of the separator

        // Convert each string to number. Because we cannot use stoi, tokenize functions
        // we have to do it by ourselves.
        int score_x = 0;
        while( *str_x != ':'){ // until separator
            score_x = score_x*10 + (*str_x - '0');
            str_x++;
        }
        int score_y = 0;
        while( *str_y != '\0'){ // until NULL
            score_y = score_y*10 + (*str_y - '0');
            str_y++;
        }

        // Now compare them and give points
        if( score_x == score_y ){
            point_x++;
            point_y++;
        }else if( score_x > score_y ){
            point_x+=3;
        }else{
            point_y+=3;
        }
    }

    printf("point_x=%d   point_y=%d\n", point_x, point_y);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned points = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    int r;
    char *itr;
    for (itr = match[i]; itr != ':'; itr++);
    r = strncmp(match[i], itr + 1, itr - match[i]);
    if (!r)
        points += 1;
    else if (r > 0)
        points += 3;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a string is like "2:13". It shouldn't give points.

Answer (score 0):

If we remove all the needless and strange complexity with the pointer-to-pointer, we get this fast and readable code:

```
int main(void) 
{
  char* matchs[10] = { "2:3",  "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", 
                       "55:7", "7:2", "17:2",  "2:17", "17:18" };

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("%s ", matchs[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The only case where it would make a bit of sense to use `char**` is when the amount of strings are unknown and they are terminated with a *sentinel value* such as NULL. That's a less ideal situation than knowing the amount of items in advance, and therefore somewhat slower to execute. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void) 
{
  char* matchs[10+1] = { "2:3",  "0:0", "15:12", "2:13", "1:5", 
                         "55:7", "7:2", "17:2",  "2:17", "17:18", NULL };

  for(char** ptr=matchs; *ptr != NULL; ptr++)
  {
    printf("%s ", *ptr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

From there on you can convert each item to integers if you please instead of the `printf` calls. That's another task, for which you may want to use `strtoul`.